# why doesn't std::remove_copy_if() actually remove?

Tags: c++, stl

Could this be the worst named function in the STL? (rhetorical question)

std::remove_copy_if() doesn't actually appear to do any *removing*. As best I can tell, it behaves more like copy_if_not.

The negation is a bit confusing, but can be worked around with std::not1(), however I might be misunderstanding something as I cannot fathom what this function has to do with removing - am I missing something?

If not, is there an STL algorithm for conditionally removing (moving?) elements from a container & putting them in another container?

Editing to add an example so readers are less confused.

The following program appears to leave the input range (V1) untouched:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (void)
{
    std::vector<int> V1, V2;
    V1.push_back(-2);
    V1.push_back(0);
    V1.push_back(-1);
    V1.push_back(0);
    V1.push_back(1);
    V1.push_back(2);

    std::copy(V1.begin(), V1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    std::remove_copy_if(
        V1.begin(),
        V1.end(),
        std::back_inserter(V2),
        std::bind2nd(std::less<int>(), 0));

    std::copy(V2.begin(), V2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    std::copy(V1.begin(), V1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

It outputs:

```
-2 0 -1 0 1 2 
0 0 1 2 
-2 0 -1 0 1 2
```

I was expecting so see something like:

```
-2 0 -1 0 1 2 
0 0 1 2 
0 0 1 2 ? ? ?
```

Where ? could be any value. But I was surprised to see that the input range was untouched, & that the return value is not able to be used with (in this case) std::vector::erase(). (The return value is an *output* iterator.)

Comment: Hey Luc, yeah, I get that remove functions shuffle elements to the end of the container, but I am not seeing that with std::remove_copy_if(). The input range appears to be untouched.

Comment: You're right, my comment was misleading.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Could this be the worst named function in the STL?

A bit of background information: in the standard library (or the original STL), there are three concepts, the containers, the iterators into those containers and algorithms that are applied to the iterators. Iterators serve as a cursor and accessor into the elements of a range but do not have a reference to the container (as mentioned before, there might not even be an underlying container).

This separation has the nice feature that you can apply algorithms to ranges of elements that do not belong to a container (consider iterator adaptors like `std::istream_iterator` or `std::ostream_iterator`) or that, belonging to a container do not consider all elements (`std::sort( v.begin(), v.begin()+v.size()/2 )` to short the first half of the container).

The negative side is that, because the algorithm (and the iterator) don't really know of the container, they cannot really modify it, they can only modify the stored elements (which is what they can access). Mutating algorithms, like `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` work on this premise: they overwrite elements that don't match the condition effectively *removing* them from the container, but they do not modify the container, only the contained values, that is up to the caller in a second step of the *erase-remove* idiom:

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), pred ),
         v.end() );
```

Further more, for mutating algorithms (those that perform changes), like `std::remove` there is a non-mutating version named by adding `copy` to the name: `std::remove_copy_if`. None of the `XXXcopyYYY` algorithms are considered to change the input sequence (although they can if you use aliasing iterators).

While this is really no excuse for the naming of `std::remove_copy_if`, I hope that it helps understanding what an algorithm does given its name: `remove_if` will modify *contents* of the range and yield a range for which all elements that match the predicate have been *removed* (the returned range is that formed by the first argument to the algorithm to the returned iterator). `std::remove_copy_if` does the same, but rather than modifying the underlying sequence, it creates a *copy* of the sequence in which those elements matching the predicate have been removed. That is, all **copy** algorithms are equivalent to *copy* and then apply the original algorithm (note that the equivalence is logical, `std::remove_copy_if` only requires an *OutputIterator*, which means that it could not possibly *copy* and then walk the copied range applying `std::remove_if`.

The same line of reasoning can be applied to other mutating algorithms: `reverse` reverses the *values* (remember, iterators don't access the container) in the range, `reverse_copy` copies the elements in the range to separate range in the reverse order.

> If not, is there an STL algorithm for conditionally removing (moving?) elements from a container & putting them in another container?

There is no such algorithm in the STL, but it could be easily implementable:

```
template <typename FIterator, typename OIterator, typename Pred>
FIterator splice_if( FIterator first, FIterator last, OIterator out, Pred p )
{
   FIterator result = first;
   for ( ; first != last; ++first ) {
      if ( p( *first ) ) {
         *result++ = *first;
      } else {
         *out++ = *first;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: " but they do not modify the container at all" really bad wording.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Thanks for pointing out. Modified, not sure if it is clearer, I hope so :)

Comment: You're needlessly copying the elements onto themselves until the first one does not satisfy the predicate. You could start your algorithm at `std::find_if_not(first, last, pred)` to skip the prefix that does not need to be moved to the new output range instead.

Answer (score 5):

> is there an STL algorithm for conditionally removing (moving?) elements from a container & putting them in another container?

The closest thing I can think of is [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
std::vector<int> v;
// ...
auto it = std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), pick_the_good_elements);
std::vector<int> w(std::make_move_iter(it), std::make_move_iter(v.end()));
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

Now `v` will contain the "good" elements, and `w` will contain the "bad" elements.

Comment: @fred--std::make_move_iter(it)- it hopefully move the iterator `it` and  `v.end` afterward will the both will be available for v.erase(it, v.end());,becuase once move has done on any source i read it will reset to almost null_ptr, does my comment make sense?

Answer (score 2):

> If not, is there an STL algorithm for conditionally removing (moving?) elements from a container & putting them in another container?

Not really. The idea is that the modifying algorithms are allowed to "move" (not in the C++ sense of the word) elements in a container around but cannot change the length of the container. So the `remove` algorithms could be called `prepare_for_removal`.

By the way, C++11 provides [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), which allows you to copy selected elements from one container to another without playing funny logic games with `remove_copy_if`.

Comment: Hi juanchopanza, yep, I initially had 2 lines of code: copy_if() & remove_if(). Then I spotted remove_copy_if() & thought I hit the motherlode but was surprised when it did not behave as I expected. I was expecting the copied elements to be shuffled toward the end of the input range.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that is what it does... std::remove_copy_if copies the vector, removing anything that matches the pred.

std::remove_if ... removes on condition (or rather, shuffles things around).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `remove` is not the best name for this family of functions.

But as Luc said, there's a reason for it working the way it does, and the [GoTW item](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/051.htm) that he mentions explains how it works. `remove_if` works exactly the same way as remove - which is what you would expect.

You might also want to read this [Wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove).

Comment: BTW, the short answer to your question "Why doesn't `remove` actually remove?" is that remove is only passed iterators, and has no way to access the underlying container, so it can't actually remove elements from the container.

Comment: Even shorter: `remove_if` also works on an `int[5]`. Nobody can remove elements from that.